# Alternatives to STRIKE AS A RATHER ODD

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Are there any phrases or idiomatic ways of replacing **it strikes as a rather odd** in the context of the following sentence

> It however **strikes** the examiner **as a rather odd** that the candidate did not include a proper analysis on the issue

Comment: What difference in meaning do you want to convey with a different word or phrase?

Comment: "It seems rather strange to the examiner..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the "a" before "rather". The word "odd" is an adjective, and "rather" is an adverb of degree. Since "odd" is an adjective, you don't use the article "a" with it.

> However, it strikes the examiner **as rather odd** that the candidate did not include a proper analysis on the issue.

(If I were writing the sentence, I would start it "However, it strikes...", not "It however strikes ...")

The sentence would also be grammatical as

> However, it strikes the examiner **as a rather odd thing** that the candidate...

With the addition of the noun "thing", an article "a" would be required.